# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A KCQL error occurred.FIELD_ID is not a valid field name

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry, attunity

I have data stored into a kafka topic and i want to move to cassandra using the `CassandraSinkConnector` from landoop.

I am having this error while i am trying to start the connector:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A KCQL error occurred.FIELD_ID is not a valid field name
at com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.converters.Transform$.raiseException$1(Transform.scala:40)
at com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.converters.Transform$.apply(Transform.scala:83)
at com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraJsonWriter$$anonfun$com$datamountaineer$streamreactor$connect$cassandra$sink$CassandraJsonWriter$$insert$1.apply(CassandraJsonWriter.scala:182)
at com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraJsonWriter$$anonfun$com$datamountaineer$streamreactor$connect$cassandra$sink$CassandraJsonWriter$$insert$1.apply(CassandraJsonWriter.scala:181)
at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.foreach(Map.scala:116)
```

Seems the schema has something that schema registry validation doesn`t like, but i dont get what is the problem. This is my schema (this is autogenerated from Attunity Replicate):

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "DataRecord",
  "namespace": "com.attunity.queue.msg.test 1 dlx express.DCSDBA.PURGE_SETUP",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "data",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Data",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "FIELD_ID",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "string"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "SERVER_INSTANCE",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "int"
            ],
            "default": null
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "beforeData",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "Data"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "headers",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Headers",
        "namespace": "com.attunity.queue.msg",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "operation",
            "type": {
              "type": "enum",
              "name": "operation",
              "symbols": [
                "INSERT",
                "UPDATE",
                "DELETE",
                "REFRESH"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "changeSequence",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "timestamp",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "streamPosition",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "transactionId",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "changeMask",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "bytes"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "columnMask",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "bytes"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "transactionEventCounter",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "long"
            ],
            "default": null
          },
          {
            "name": "transactionLastEvent",
            "type": [
              "null",
              "boolean"
            ],
            "default": null
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my sink configuration:

```
connector.class=com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraSinkConnector
connect.cassandra.key.space=eucsarch
topics=DCSDBA.PURGE_SETUP1
tasks.max=1
connect.cassandra.mapping.collection.to.json=false
connect.cassandra.kcql=INSERT INTO purge_setup SELECT data.* FROM DCSDBA.PURGE_SETUP1
connect.cassandra.password=pass
connect.cassandra.username=user
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://schema-registry:8081
connect.cassandra.contact.points=cassandra.local
connect.cassandra.port=9042
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://schema-registry:8081
```

Comment: Can you share the configuration of your sink connector as well ?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous configuration added  to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a couple of similar issues with Kafka Connect and Attunity Replicate. Although I'd have to take a look at your original data stream, the following SMT did the trick for me:

```
"transforms":"ExtractField",
"transforms.ExtractField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Value",
"transforms.ExtractField.field":"data"
```

Comment: oh boy! you made my day! the problem was this extra "data" wrapper that adds Attunity, i tried to remove that from Attunity Replicate ui but, no success, Only your solution worked. Huge thanks mate!